# How can I get rid of the error I get when I want the audio features of a currently playing track on Spotify API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spotify

So I have this code where I use a var to get the audio features of the currently playing song. I have the code already but I get this error saying

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined*.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Please explain it as simply as possible I'm a beginner.

[image: The error I see in my console]

Here is the code as text:

```
setInterval(function(){
    callAjax();
}, 1000);

var apiData;
var audioData;

var callAjax = function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
        success: function(response) {
          userCurrentlyPlaceholder.innerHTML = userCurrentlyTemplate(response);

          apiData = response;
          console.log(response);
          $('#login').hide();
          $('#loggedin').show();
        }
    });

    if (apiData = ! undefined){
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features/" + apiData.item.id,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
            },
            success: function(response) {
                userFeaturePlaceholder.innerHTML = userFeatureTemplate(response);

                audioData = response;
                console.log(response);
                $('#login').hide();
                $('#loggedin').show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code as text not an image

Comment: the 401 error means that it's unauthorized.  It's a bad access token or API key.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong with the undefined-check before your second ajax call. It should probably read `apiData != undefined`, but what you have is `apiData = ! undefined`. This effectively sets `apiData` to `!undefined` which evaluates to true. Assuming you successfully retrieved `apiData`, this data is then lost and any subsequent attempt to access anything will fail.

```
var apiData = {"item": {"id": 123}};
console.assert(apiData.item.id == 123);
console.assert(apiData != undefined);
apiData = ! undefined;
console.log(apiData);
console.assert(apiData.item.id == 123);
```

It may well be that that the first ajax call failed because of unauthorized access and apiData is undefined anyways.